# How to derive segwit addresses from an extended public key?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoinj, bitcoin-wallet-app

I tried to use the following code:

```
    DeterministicKey key = DeterministicKey.deserializeB58(null , "xpub...", MAINNET);



    DeterministicHierarchy hierarchy = new DeterministicHierarchy(key)
;
    DeterministicKey chain = hierarchy.deriveChild(key.getPath(), false, false, new ChildNumber(0, false));
    DeterministicKey index = hierarchy.deriveChild(chain.getPath(), false, false, new ChildNumber(0, false));
    SegwitAddress segwitAddress = SegwitAddress.fromHash(MAINNET, index.getPubKeyHash());
```

But it doesn't return correct address. 
Any help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zpub's would be needed for native segwit addresses. And current bitcoinj master branch does not support Zpub, it support xpub and xpub's would always derive to
legacy addresses. Give a try to Segwit branch that may helps. Also take a look at [this](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/pull/1563)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems similar to the given link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitcoinj/F7smdvlCbnE

Try to use bitcoinjs for the same extended public key. or try the provided solutions.

Hope this will work in your case.

Comment: how to use bitcoinjs for extended public key in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) Python library.

```
from btctools import Xpub

>>> extended = Xpub.decode('xpub123...')
>>> child = extended/0/0
>>> child.key.to_address('P2WPKH')
'bc1q0xedk29m3z0ja0l5xl2avclrhkd8y9z5au5wyt'
```

Comment: how can use this python lib in java ?